# Behavior of Scalar::Util::looks_like_number in Perl

Tags: perl

I am trying to find out if an input is number or string. I came across `looks_like_number` and cannot understand the values it returns.

```
use warnings;
use Scalar::Util qw(looks_like_number);

my $name = 11;
print looks_like_number ($name);
```

This code prints `1` if `$name` contains a string and a static number if `$name` contains an integer (i.e. 4352 for each integer).

I am using Perl on Windows.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is what the [documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/Scalar/Util.html) says:

> looks_like_number EXPR
>
> Returns true if perl thinks EXPR is a number. See "looks_like_number" in perlapi.

The [link to perlapi](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlapi.html#looks_like_number) in this quote is not really helping us a lot unfortunately:

> Test if the content of an SV looks like a number (or is a number). Inf
> and Infinity are treated as numbers (so will not issue a non-numeric
> warning), even if your atof() doesn't grok them. Get-magic is ignored.
>
> ```
> I32   looks_like_number(SV *const sv)
> ```

In my case, your code will return an integer that is not `0`, which is true.

- I got `4352` when I used `11`.
- When I used `'11'` I got `1`.

All of these are true, so that works.

- When I put `'test'` or `'foobar'` I got `0`, which is not true.
- I never got a `1` for anything that did not look like a number.
- I tried `'1e1'` and it printed `4`, which is a true value, and the input looked like a number in scientific notation.

So, I'd say it always returns something true if Perl thinks the input looks like a number, though I do not know what exactly that true value represents. I cannot confirm that it also returns true with a name.

Comment: The Perl function `looks_like_number` and the C function `looks_like_number` are not the same function! And they do not return the same thing.

Answer (score 21):

You forgot to ask a question! Here are two possibilities.

### Why doesn't it always return the same value for true?

Why not? It returns a true value as documented. It makes no difference which true value it is.

### What is the value returned?

If the scalar contains a string, it uses `grok_number` which has specific document return values.

> The type of the number is returned (`0` if unrecognised), otherwise it is a bit-ORed combination of `IS_NUMBER_IN_UV`, `IS_NUMBER_GREATER_THAN_UV_MAX`, `IS_NUMBER_NOT_INT`, `IS_NUMBER_NEG`, `IS_NUMBER_INFINITY`, `IS_NUMBER_NAN` (defined in `perl.h`).

Otherwise, it uses

```
SvFLAGS(sv) & (SVf_NOK|SVp_NOK|SVf_IOK|SVp_IOK)
```

You can't tell which of the two was used, so you can't ascribe meaning to the value, which is why it's undocumented.

Answer (score 7):

Don't rely on the exact numerical value. This is an abstraction leak, which the latest version of `Scalar::Util` (1.39) fixes. What is important is simply the truth of the result, not its exact numerical value.

See bug https://rt.cpan.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=94806