# Side-effect of Perl's print function

Tags: perl

I'm wondering why/how `print` in Perl can have a side-effect.

```
use Scalar::Util qw/looks_like_number/; 

my @A = (5, '2', 'aaa', 1, 'aab'); 

my @a = map { looks_like_number($_) } @A; 
print "1) @a\n";
# prints "4352 1 0 4352 0"

print "A print with a side-effect: @A\n";

@a = map { looks_like_number($_) } @A; 
print "2) @a\n";
# prints "1 1 0 1 0"
```

In this example, `looks_like_number` returns `4352 1 0 4352 0` before the print, and `1 1 0 1 0` after the print.

What does `print` do to these values to affect how they're interpreted by `looks_like_number`?

Comment: print should mark scalars that they were used as strings.

Comment: I don't have an answer but I found out that it's not print that does the side effect but the string extrapolation. You can do `"@A";` instead of the print and it will still mess with the second output.

Comment: Nit: The whole point of `print` (making something appears on the terminal or whatnot) is also a side-effect.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When interpolating or otherwise concatenating a numeric value, a stringified version needs to be created. This string is stored within the scalar (in addition to the numeric value) for later use, and this can affect which value `looks_like_number` returns.

---

To inspect variables' internals, use [Devel::Peek](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Devel::Peek)<sup>[1]</sup>.

```
use Devel::Peek qw( Dump );
my @A = (5, '2', 'aaa');
Dump($_) for @A;  # Or: Dump(\@A);
print "@A\n";
Dump($_) for @A;
```

With Perl 5.20, you get the following: (Rerranged for readability)

```
Before                             After
===============================    ===============================
SV = IV(0x4532a78) at 0x4532a88    SV = PVIV(0x45563a0) at 0x4532a88
  REFCNT = 2                         REFCNT = 2
  FLAGS = (IOK,pIOK)                 FLAGS = (IOK,POK,pIOK,pPOK)
  IV = 5                             IV = 5
                                     PV = 0x454a870 "5"\0
                                     CUR = 1
                                     LEN = 10

SV = PV(0x45336a0) at 0x4532c08    SV = PV(0x45336a0) at 0x4532c08
  REFCNT = 2                         REFCNT = 2
  FLAGS = (POK,IsCOW,pPOK)           FLAGS = (POK,IsCOW,pPOK)
  PV = 0x455cf00 "2"\0               PV = 0x455cf00 "2"\0
  CUR = 1                            CUR = 1
  LEN = 10                           LEN = 10
  COW_REFCNT = 1                     COW_REFCNT = 1

SV = PV(0x4533720) at 0x4550b90    SV = PV(0x4533720) at 0x4550b90
  REFCNT = 2                         REFCNT = 2
  FLAGS = (POK,IsCOW,pPOK)           FLAGS = (POK,IsCOW,pPOK)
  PV = 0x455f210 "aaa"\0             PV = 0x455f210 "aaa"\0
  CUR = 3                            CUR = 3
  LEN = 10                           LEN = 10
  COW_REFCNT = 1                     COW_REFCNT = 1
```

Look at the `FLAGS`. When provided a number, the stringification of the number is cached (stored in the scalar) for future use. This is the side-effect mentioned.

The value returned by `looks_like_number` is sometimes a subset of the bits of `FLAGS`<sup>[2]</sup>. This is why the specific value returned varies. It will still return true if it returned true before, and it will still return false if it returned false before.

---

1. [illguts](http://search.cpan.org/dist/illguts/) provides information on the format of scalars.
2. See [Behavior of Scalar::Util's `looks_like_number`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19201234/589924).

Comment: `IsCOW` is an amusing acronym :)

Comment: @Zaid, Moo. (COW = Copy On Write, an optimization introduced in 5.20.)

Comment: If I understand this correctly, the gist of this is that when printing a numeric value, a stringified version needs to be created. This string is stored within the scalar for later use, which affects the behavior of `looks_like_number`.

Comment: @AKHolland, Close. s/printing/concatenating/. `print` doesn't do it, but interpolating into a string (concatenating) does. I added a summary to the top of my answer derived from your comment.

Comment: Be aware; latest version of `Scalar::Util` fixes this particular abstraction leak - `looks_like_number` will now always return simply 0 or 1.

Comment: @LeoNerd, Code couldn't reliably rely on the value even before this change, as I explained in the linked node. (Nit: I suspect the latest version returns `0/""`, not `0`.)

Comment: @LeoNerd, No, it actually does return `0`. Why construct a new scalar instead of using `looks_like_number(sv) ? &PL_sv_yes : &PL_sv_no`?

Comment: @ikegami Oh - good point. That's what PL_sv_yes/no are for after all. I'll pop that in