# What happens to a non-matching regex in a Perl subroutine call?

Tags: perl

I'm trying to make sense of what's happening with a non-matching regex in a subroutine call. Consider this script:

```
sub routine{
    print Dumper(\@_);
}

my $s = 'abc123';

# These pass a single element to &routine
&routine( $s =~ /c/ );      # 1. passes (1)
&routine(2 == 3);           # 2. passes ('')
&routine(3 == 3);           # 3. passes (1)

# The following two calls appear to be identical 
&routine( $s =~ /foobar/ ); # 4. passes ()
&routine();                 # 5. passes ()
```

In the above script, numbers 1, 2 and 3 all pass a single value to `&routine`. I'm surprised that number 4 doesn't pass a false value, but rather passes nothing at all!

It doesn't seem possible that the non-matching regex evaluates to nothing at all, since the same sort of signature in a conditional isn't valid:

```
# This is fine
if( $s =~ /foobar/ ){
   print "it's true!\n";
}

# This is a syntax error
if( ){
   print "Hmm...\n"; # :/
}
```

What happens to the non-matching regex when it's used in a subroutine call? Further, is it possible for `&routine` to figure out whether or not it's been called with a non-matching regex, vs nothing at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the match operator [`=~`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Binding-Operators) is used in list context it returns a list of matches. When there are no matches this list is empty (also called the empty list), and the empty list is passed to your sub `routine` which in turn causes `@_` to be empty.

If you explicitly want to pass the false value of "Did this expression return any matches?" you need to perform your match in scalar context. You can do this by using the [`scalar`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/scalar.html) keyword

```
&routine( scalar $s =~ /foobar/ );
```

which will pass the value `''`(false) to your `routine` sub. Calling a sub without any arguments effectively passes this empty list, so your final example would be correctly written:

```
if ( () ) {
   print "Hmm...\n";
}
```

which is not a syntax error because in Perl `0`, `''`, and `()` all represent false.

Comment: What about the latter question? Can a subroutine know how it's been called (i.e. with nothing, or with an empty list)?

Comment: @ajwood: Why would you want your subroutine to be aware of the source of its arguments? If you must know that the parameter is the result of a regex match then pass a second parameter to say so

Comment: @ajwood arguments to subroutines are evaluated before being passed to the sub. So there is no difference between calling a sub with an expression that results in the empty list or calling it with no arguments at all. I don't believe this can be detected.

Comment: @Borodin I want to write a `bool` sub which can make the value of a boolean more predictable.

Comment: @Borodin For example, in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24412431/512652), a True return value can sometimes be one, and other times be a larger integer. I'm in a situation where I'd like my truth values to be predictable.

Comment: @ajwood `sub bool { my $truthiness = shift; return $truthiness ? 1 : 0; }`

Comment: @HunterMcMillen That's exactly what I've got :) I tend to like writing subs that check their arguments for sanity; in this case, I'd like the sub to die if it wasn't given exactly one argument. But it's looking like I'll make an exception in this case :)

Comment: @ajwood: The problem is that, say, an empty string `""` in list context is true. A bare `return` handles this by returning an empty list in list conttext, and `undef` in scalar context so it is always *false*. I think you are plugging a hole that doesn't exist, and probably because you are more familiar with a language that handles Boolean values differently

Comment: @ajwood: no, a subroutine can't distinguish whether it was called with no parameters or an expression yeilding an empty list.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen: The problem with that is that `if ( my @x = bool(0) )` will succeed

Comment: @ajwood: You can pass a scalar true/false value with `routine( scalar $s =~ /foobar/ )` but I really think you're trying to program in a different language. By the way, don't call subroutines with an ampersand `&`. That hasn't been correct practice for over twenty years

Comment: @Borodin Your assessment of my situation is accurate, thanks :)

Comment: @Borodin How about `sub bool { my $truthiness = shift; return $truthiness ? 1 : (wantarray ? () : 0); }` :)

Comment: @HunterMcMillen: A bare return is already context-sensitive, so you could write `sub bool { shift ? return 1 : return }`

Comment: @Borodin fair point, that is much easier to understand as well